# efood after web application installation i get infinite loading and errors in console

Tags: flutter, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaKWn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewapt.png)

after installing efood application from https://codecanyon.net/item/efood-food-delivery-system-with-laravel-admin-panel-delivery-man-app-v10/30320338 and doing all the configurations when compiling and running on the web these are the errors i got i need to know how to solve them i tried recompiling it and it still didn't work and i tried localhost it still gave me the same errors

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198). You appear to be attempting an asynchronous web request from one domain (order.kosharishobra.com) to another (admin.kosharishobra.com) without the destination domain supplying a response header to indicate that the source domain is allowed to do this. Reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors may help, or you can google "CORS" (cross origin resource sharing)